# Selecting between the MIN date and MIN date + 11 months - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that lists an ID, a month, and a value. I'd like to query this table to find the `min(month) where value <= 0`.

I'm having trouble writing this in a way that doesn't call the same table multiple times as the table is about 10mm rows.

So far, what I've written uses a `HAVING` clause to check if the `month between min(month) and min(month) + 11` but it isn't functioning correctly. The query returns no data.

```
select id, month from table 
group by id 
having month between min(month) and date_add(min(month), interval 11 month)
```

Is there a clean way to do this without nesting queries and calling the same table multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to scan the table twice.  Basically, the query is something like this:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, min(yyyymm) as minyyyymm
      from t
      where val < 0
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id and t.yyyymm >= minyyyymm and
        t.yyyymm <= minyyyymm + interval 11 month;
```

One option for making this faster is to materialize the subquery and add an index on `id`.